# jquery events not triggered if dom is populated via jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

just want to ask if someone has done a workaround regarding jquery events not being called when field is created using jquery or ajax.

I have a date field in which works fine if it coded using the default html code. What I want to do is I can add as many dates as i want but the **`.datepicker()`** event was not triggered if it is created using jquery.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "date_fld">
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button class = "add">Add new Date</button>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
     $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        $(".date_fld").append('<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>');
     });
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be appending multiple elements with the same Id to the dom. You could have an increasing variable to run something like the following

```
<script>
  var x = 0;
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
    $(".date_fld").append('<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker' + x + '"></p>');
    $( "#datepicker" + x ).datepicker();
    x++;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if you are using the ID selector jQuery will only ever return the first instance. If at all possible you should avoid duplicate IDs because it will break a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
<script>
     $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        $(".date_fld").append('<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>');
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the above answers doesnt work for you, just FYI u can use this code i use when everything fails.

```
function loadjsfile(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}

loadjsfile("myscript.js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
```

This code will make your html load a js file inside.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the new object to a variable, append it, then initialize the datepicker to get around having to search the DOM for the newly created element first.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
    var newDatePicker = $('<p>Date: <input type="text"></p>');
    $(".date_fld").append(newDatePicker);
    newDatePicker.datepicker();
 });
```